# Access to website/website correct?

Tags: windows, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, automation, coded-ui-tests

I want a simple flexible (means to change the url as needed) automated coded ui test in visual studio 2012, that checks whether a/many (sharepoint-)website/s are working fine.

My solution is to enter the checking url and the expected title of browser in  MS testmanager. The coded ui test opens the browser, read the url and the title from testmanager, calls the checking website and verifies the title of browser. At the end the browser will close and the procedure starts with the next testwebsite.
The problem is, I must enter all titles for test in VS ("UIMap.uitest - UI Control Map - Properies - Windows Titles"). Therewith the test is very inflexible. (I want to get the testingdata only in MS testmanager) Besides - the title isn´t a warranty that the website built correct.

Have you any idea how I can do more efficient my "access-to-website-test"?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try using `NavigateToUrl()` to go the the website you want and then doing a basic assertion to see if it loads, there's probably even a method called `VerifyPageLoads()` or something even.

Comment: Hallo. Thank you for the answer. The problem with "NavigateToUrl()" is: I don´t know how I can catch the open browser automated. AND I´m not sure whether I can use the "page-load"-method in Coded-UI-Test.

Answer (score 1):

You could data drive your test putting the URL and any other data that needs to change in different columns (ie fields) of the data source. It is quite valid to data drive with just one set of data.

Comment: Hallo. Thank you for the answer. I´m not sure, whether I understand you. There are as many websites (and possibilities for check) and so are many datasets. In my opinion it is this too much. Besides I want to say automatically, which criterion is to check. ...

Comment: @Rotaney so how many (approximately) different URLs and how many different values need to be entered or modified to swap from one URL to another? Could you have a list of URLs plus the other values in the test program, then use a parameter similar to your current method to choose an entry from the list?

Comment: @Rotaney If you want to test all the URLs one after another then data driving is the way to go. My words about just one set of data were because I thought you wanted to test just one URL.

Comment: Hi. You are right. I can use a list of urls and parameters for test. This works! My requirement is the tester can change my list of urls and the test parameter (for example the title of browser) flexible. At the moment I must adapt in Visual Studio 2012 the changes.